# Choosing a dynamic Selected option in HTML form

Tags: php, html, sql

I have this dropdown select with employee names:

```
 <select class="form-control" id="assignee" name="assignee" style="max-width: 300px;">
     <option value="Employee 1">Employee 1</option>
     <option value="Employee 2">Employee 2</option>
     <option value="Employee 3">Employee 3</option>                             
 </select>
```

The initial value is chosen by an administrator and CAN be changed in a second form using the UPDATE SQL feature:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE `jobs_canjobs` SET `job_name`='$job_name',`comments`='{$comments}',`due_date`='$newdate',`assignee`='$assignee',`assign_email`='$assign_email',`AE`='$AE',`Property`='$property' WHERE job_numb = '$job_numb'";
```

However, every time they make any change to the form, the initial option is selected, thereby CHANGING the `$assignee` and `$assign_email`. I have tried to use the variable user `selected` but I think this is the wrong approach to make sure the user doesn't constantly change.

How can I make sure the Employee selected comes up on the EDIT form?

Comment: May I honestly ask what the downvote is for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: learn about [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (PDO for short) and start
using prepared  statements immediately to  make your final  product more
secure.

You're correct about `select`, just that you need an extra step: perform
a query  to find the  current selected  value for your  `assignee`. This
might be  not needed if you  are already retrieving the  proper database
row in your edit form. I guess you're doing so, to populate the form. If
not, use a query to retrieve this particular column or other extra ones,
like:

```
SELECT assignee FROM jobs_canjobs WHERE job_numb=?
```

Now, you probably have your array  of possible employees to generate the
options. If it looks something like this:

```
$employees = [
    'Employee 1',
    'Employee 2',
    'Employee 3'
];

$assignee = /* find out who is the current one in DB, as discussed */
```

…then you can proceed with generating your options with:

```
<select class="form-control" id="assignee" name="assignee">
  <?php foreach ($employees as $e) : ?>
    <option value="<?= $e ?>" <?php
      if ($assignee == $e) echo 'selected'
    ?>><?= $e ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: There are other topics undiscussed here, like using inline CSS (try to avoid that) and the fact that your option tags suggest you are not storing this in a relational database fashion. Generally, you'd have a table for employees and reference their ID in the assignee column. Then you can retrieve a list of employees from the database and also use their ID in the `<option>` value.

Comment: I have heard that is a better method (ID of employee) to choose the assignee, but as I am newer to PHP I didn't want to OVER complicate a form that I wrote in two days.

As for the Inline CSS, thank you. Just being lazy and not wanting to edit the bootstrap to add an extra class. Inline won't hurt, it's just not clean.

Comment: This is an excellent answer and I think it fits the requisite better.

Comment: I am confused by this line: `$assignee = /* find out who is the current one in DB, as discussed */` What would go after that?

Answer (score 0):

Best answer for now that I thought of was to create another `<option>` field with the echo SQL of the chosen user:

```
 <select class="form-control" id="assignee" name="assignee" style="max-width: 300px;">
    <option value="<? echo $assignee;?>" selected><? echo $assignee;?></option>
    <option value="Employee 1">Employee 1</option>
    <option value="Employee 2">Employee 2</option>
    <option value="Employee 3">Employee 3</option>
```

and have THAT be the selected, so unless action is taken by the editor it cannot change.